# Getting java.io.IOException: Stream closed error without explicitly closing it

Tags: java, fileoutputstream, zipinputstream

My zipInputStream is getting closed after writing the first file itself even though I am not closing any of the streams.

```
 ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(inputStream); 
 ZipEntry zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
  while (zipEntry != null) {

        modelFolderName = <somefoldername>
        modelFileName = <somefilename>

        String FILE_STORAGE_LOCATION = env.getProperty("workspacePath");

        File folder = new File(FILE_STORAGE_LOCATION + "/" + modelFolderName );
        if(!folder.exists()) {
            folder.mkdirs();
        }

        try (FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(FILE_STORAGE_LOCATION + "/" +  modelFolderName + "/" + modelFileName)) {
            try (BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(zipInputStream)) {
              byte[] buffer = new byte[8096];
              while (true) {
                int count = in.read(buffer);
                if (count == -1) {
                  break;
                }
                fout.write(buffer, 0, count);
              }
            }
        }
        zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
    }
```

Comment: Are you missing code? Because you're only checking the first stream entry. Loop over the zipEntries, not over only one entry

Comment: In your second try-with-resources you are wrapping `zipInputStream` into a `BufferedInputStream` which gets closed after the try and closes the underlying Stream which is also used for `zipInputStream`

Comment: Also it appears that you're consuming the entire stream inside your try block rather than just the entry

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Dont just put the exception message in the title of the question. Add the relevant parts of the exception stack trace to the question, and clearly identify which line of your code throws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the syntax *try-with-resource*. Everything inside the parenthesis will be closed automatically as if there is a finally block to close it.

When `in` is closed in the implicit finally block, `zipInputStream` will also be closed because `BufferedInputStream` is a subclass of `FilterInputStream`, which closes its source when itself get closed.

(In general, most classes implementing `Closable` release any resources associated when `close` is called)

To see the implementation of `FilterInputStream::close`
https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/io/FilterInputStream.java

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: @GhostCat I added more explanation to it.

Comment: Given the amount of information we have here, I now tend to agree with you ;-)